# In SQL Server, do composite primary keys increase the chance of a deadlock?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if, either because of increased row locking, and/or because of increased time spent holding locks, having a composite primary key defined on a table would increase the chance of having a deadlock when a it is being updated my multiple threads at once?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using composite PKs and are inserting large amounts of data in parallel you might get hit by **resource hash collision**. See ["The Curious Case of the Dubious Deadlock and the Not So Logical Lock"](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamesrowlandjones/archive/2009/05/28/the-curious-case-of-the-dubious-deadlock-and-the-not-so-logical-lock.aspx) for a real world example.

And for the explanation to **resource hash collision** I'll cite Remus Rusanu in ["%%lockres%% collision probability magic marker: 16,777,215"](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/29/lockres-collision-probability-magic-marker-16777215/) (recommended read):

> The lock manager in SQL Server doesn’t know what it locks, it just locks ‘resources’ (basically strings). It is the job of higher level components like the the access methods of the storage engine to present the ‘resource’ to the lock manager and ask for the desired lock. When locking rows in a heap or a b-tree the storage engine will synthesize a ‘resource’ from the record identifier. Since these resources have a limited length, the storage engine has to reduce the effective length of a key to the maximum length is allowed to present to the lock manager, and that means that the record’s key will be reduced to 6 bytes. This is achieved by hashing the key into a 6 byte hash value.

[...]

> On 6 bytes there are 281,474,976,710,656 distinct possible values. Its a pretty big number? Not that big actually. [...] So the SQL %%lockres%% hash will produce two records with same hash, with a 50% probability, out of the table, any table, of only 16,777,215 record.

Comment: Great info.  Do you think there would be any difference in single PK of Int32 versus a composite PK of Int16, Int16?

Comment: @Blam: Can't tell you, as I don't know SQL Server internals that well. But a single PK should guarantee you no deadlocks (as mentioned at the end of the first linked article). It depends on how SQL Server hashes those composite keys to tell for sure.

Comment: +1 That article deals primarily with inserts.  The question is on "updated by multiple threads at once".  Do you conclude single PK would guarantee no deadlock on update?

Comment: @MicSim: Does the hash function make a discrimiantion against composite PKs? Is it better (for avoiding collisions) to have a `CHAR(3), INT, CHAR(2)` (9 bytes composite key) or a 36-byte single-column GUID?

Comment: @ypercube: I don't know how the hash function works, maybe some SQL Server expert can help out. It all depends on the internal implementation how good the hash distribution is.

Comment: I don't know either and that why I asked. Your answer seems to imply that there is though (a difference) in how hash behaves with composite and simple PKs. At least that's how I read it.

Comment: But are the differences because of the composite/single or because of the size of the PKs?

Comment: @ypercube That article refers to SQL 2005.  With 2008R2 there were some fixes to lockhash and specifically addressed composite.

Answer (score 3):

Since the SQL Server’s Lock Manager uses a lockhash value (not the PK directly) I would conclude there is no difference in locking using a single column PK versus a composite PK.

[Improvement in minimizing lockhash key collisions in SQL Server 2008R2 and its impact on concurrency](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2010/01/18/improvement-in-minimizing-lockhash-key-collisions-in-sql-server-2008r2-and-its-impact-on-concurrency.aspx)

*Unlike some other database vendors, there is a logical component to SQL Server’s Lock Manager. SQL Server uses a lockhash value to represent a lock on the lock structure in the SQL Server Lock Manager instead of using the physical description to a row, page or a table. The lockhash value then is kept in memory.*

I would conclude no greater chance of getting a hash collision of the lockhash value from a single column key versus a composite key.  As indicated in the link with SQL 2008R2 the lockhash was significantly improved and specifically addressed composite keys.

Prior to 2008R2 lockhash was less than perfect for both single and composite keys.
It is a good practice to keep your PK short.

.NET KeyValuePair and Tuple do not generate a good hash.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I would tend to say no, it doesn't with well designed code.  And the reason is that the causes of deadlocks and the techniques to avoid/eliminate them are generally not time dependent.  Most deadlocks occur because of varied update paths within threads.  For example, code A does update Table1 then Update Table2 while Code Block B does an update Table2 then Update Table1.  The techniques for avoiding this relate to ensuring that the various code blocks try and update the items in the same order.  In other words, avoid scenarios where thread 1 has a lock on A and wants to update B, while thread 2 has a lock on B and wants to update A.

If there are existences of these conflicting coding blocks/statements, however, I think composite keys can increase the frequency of deadlocks occurring.  Basically, the longer a transaction takes to complete, the more time another thread has to lock the other resource and cause a deadlock.

Except for an extremely small/specific edge case, I don't believe composite keys would have an impact on the occurrence of deadlocks (at least not in my experiences).